# How to set an action for barbutton item programatically objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

Implemented some barbuttons by using below code,

```
UISegmentedControl *button = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]] autorelease];
button.momentary = YES;
button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
```

I used set action for the button using this code,

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(drawOnImageByColor:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Why are you using a segmented control, rather than a `UIButton`? A segmented control with one item doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does [button removeAllTargets:action:forControlEvents]; then [button addTarget:self....] ; work?

Comment: I wanted to set custom tint color for the button, Thats why segmented control is there. Is there other easy way.

Comment: where you want to use this bar button?

Comment: [Button setTintColor]?  Or maybe you have to access is in the subviews of the navigationController like [[[self.navigationController.subviews objectAtIndex:i]setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]];

Comment: I have used in paint application for change the brush color. There are four buttons with four colours. They are in the bottom toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change like this

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(drawOnImageByColor:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(drawOnImageByColor:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
[rightButton release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the action of the button that you are adding as custom view.